# How to change filter in CUBA Platform's DataTable

Tags: reactjs, antd, cuba-platform

In frontend, I have a DataTable built by fields. I need to change one column's filter type from select to input field. Is that possible to do with CUBA's DataTable? I do not have access to ColumnsDefinitions prop

Answer (score 0):

CUBA fronted generator create table components based on [DataTable](https://github.com/cuba-platform/frontend/blob/5fbe93a5f87f5cf586955459cf182427806e484c/packages/cuba-react-ui/src/ui/table/DataTable.tsx#L122) and [fields](https://github.com/cuba-platform/frontend/blob/5fbe93a5f87f5cf586955459cf182427806e484c/packages/cuba-react-ui/src/ui/table/DataTable.tsx#L36) property (which is deprecated). Usage of `DataTable` could be easily transformed to work with more modern [columDefinitions](https://github.com/cuba-platform/frontend/blob/5fbe93a5f87f5cf586955459cf182427806e484c/packages/cuba-react-ui/src/ui/table/DataTable.tsx#L97), which provide better control on each column.

As first step we can simply pass the same string array `fields` as `columnDefinitions` property.

```
 <DataTable
        dataCollection={this.dataCollection}
        columnDefinitions={this.fields}
        onRowSelectionChange={this.handleRowSelectionChange}
        hideSelectionColumn={true}
        buttons={buttons}
      />
```

Then we can change only needed field in array from string to column definition.

```
  ownerColumnDefinition: ColumnDefinition<Pet> = {
    field: "owner",
    columnProps: {}
  }

  fields: (string | ColumnDefinition<Pet>)[] = [
    "identificationNumber",
    "birthDate",
    "name",
    "type",
    this.ownerColumnDefinition
  ];
```

And then implement antd `filterDropdown` as described in [Ant Design Customized Filter](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-custom-filter-panel)

```
  ownerColumnDefinition: ColumnDefinition<Pet> = {
    field: "owner",
    columnProps: {
      filterDropdown: () => {/* custom filter implementation here */}
    }
  }
```

Complete example based on CUBA Petclinic app available at https://github.com/vadimbasko/cuba-petclinic-custom-table-filter, you can see customized filter with input field implemented in **PetList** component for **owner** column https://github.com/vadimbasko/cuba-petclinic-custom-table-filter/blob/0f8e7e62779d0afb0fbd733dfffabf26df754f68/modules/front/src/app/pet/PetList.tsx#L29-L70.